# what vba references do I need for access 10 app

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

So I was given a access 2010 application. I'm trying to deploy it and it was developed in access 2010 sp2. The end users do not have access on their laptops so I installed access runtime 2010. I'm now seeing references errors and I'm guessing its because the development happen in 2010 sp2, and the runtime is runtime 2010 sp1 (not sp2). Is there a way that I can see what references are actually being used for the application?

Comment: It's not the references. It's the fact it was developed with sp1 when they have sp2. You need to develop on the same service pack that your end users will have.

Comment: There is an SP2 download for the Access 2010 runtime (32-bit) [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39643).

Comment: yeah..I saw that..unfortunately access 2010 runtime sp2 is not support by IT